# Highlight errors in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nGnbJ/7/ which has the below code. I am using Bootstrap Wizard to create the tabs. What I need is that when the user submits the form from the submit button on the third tab it checks all the fields inside all tabs and highlight the tabs along with the fields that have validation errors.

The submit button only verifies and highlights the fields that are visible on the page that's on the tab which is active. The fields in the other tab are not validated at all.

This is my original issue for which I have gotten no replies 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297685/highlighting-errors-in-bootstrapwizard-sections so simplifying it with JSFiddle and basic stuff.

```
<form class="myData" id="myData1" method="post">
<div class='span12'>
     <h2>Form Wizard</h2>
</div>
<div class='span12'>
    <div id="rootwizard">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Step 3</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input name="MemberFullLegalName" class="form-control" id="MemberFullLegalName" type="text" value="" data-val-required="The Full Legal Name field is required." data-val="true">
          </input>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MemberFullLegalName"></span>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
               <input name="MemberFullLegalName1" class="form-control" id="MemberFullLegalName1" type="text" value="" data-val-required="The Full Legal Name field is required." data-val="true">
          </input>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MemberFullLegalName1"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
   <input name="MemberFullLegalName2" class="form-control" id="MemberFullLegalName2" type="text" value="" data-val-required="The Full Legal Name field is required." data-val="true">
          </input>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MemberFullLegalName2"></span>               
                 <input type="submit" name="SubmitApplication" value="Submit Application" />
            </div>           
            <ul class="pager wizard">
                <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a>

                </li>
                <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a>
                </li>

                <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a>

                </li>
                <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fiddle link didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to have "id" on every single fields in your form.

After that check with Jquery or Javascript whether they're empty field or your validation requirements.